# What app is using GPS?

Tags: iphone, gps

[image: Screenshot]

I noticed the blue title bar today in my iPhone SE 2020.
But when I look into the task list (doubleclick the home button), there is no navigation app running. I swiped up ever running app and the blue bar remains.

I suspect it is the OsmAndMaps app I installed recently. Oh wait, after I tried to make a phone call, the title bar changed to "OsmAnd Maps is Actively Using Your Location" for a few seconds.

So the question is now: how come it is using Location, but not listed in the task list?

Not that I use CarPlay and this happened after I left my car. I did not use Carplay there, but it might have done things in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Privacy > Location Services
Switch to "While Using" instead of "Always"

[image]

The arrow will tell you which apps have been using it recently.
BTW, it doesn't consume extra battery for it to do this, all it allows is permission to query your current location, which the phone itself constantly polls anyway - all you're doing is allowing it to access this info.

Comment: With regards to battery, it depends on the nature of the location requests. A navigation app *will* drain battery faster, since it's asking for continuous location updates - by default it wouldn't be this frequent.

Comment: It is already set to "While Using". It was never set to anything else. Well, except to "Not allow", which is the default and was set until I changed to "While Using".